# Docusign Email delivery issues

Tags: docusignapi

I'm experiencing issues with emails not being delivered to recipients for all the envelopes I've created with Docusign demo sandbox account created recently. I've tried email recipients with the domain gmail.com & outlook.com but not sure of the reason why email delivering is failing to these domains. I made sure by verifying Spam folders too but none of them has docusign emails delivered.

Appreciate your help in this regard!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AccountId xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">d80849c3-d316-4747-8616-523bd10a8b3d</AccountId>
  <Documents xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <Document>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Lease.pdf</Name>
      <PDFBytes>*****************</PDFBytes>
      <FileExtension>.pdf</FileExtension>
    </Document>
  </Documents>
  <Recipients xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <Recipient>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <UserName>Vamsi</UserName>
      <Email>********@gmail.com</Email>
      <Type>Signer</Type>
      <AccessCode xsi:nil="true" />
      <CaptiveInfo>
        <ClientUserId>1</ClientUserId>
      </CaptiveInfo>
    </Recipient>
  </Recipients>
  <Tabs xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <Tab>
      <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
      <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
      <PageNumber>6</PageNumber>
      <XPosition>250</XPosition>
      <YPosition>215</YPosition>
      <Type>FullName</Type>
    </Tab>
    <Tab>
      <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
      <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
      <PageNumber>6</PageNumber>
      <XPosition>70</XPosition>
      <YPosition>175</YPosition>
      <Type>SignHere</Type>
    </Tab>
    <Tab>
      <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
      <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
      <PageNumber>6</PageNumber>
      <XPosition>425</XPosition>
      <YPosition>220</YPosition>
      <Type>DateSigned</Type>
    </Tab>
  </Tabs>
  <Subject xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">eSign Lease</Subject>
  <EmailBlurb xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">Please agree to the Terms and conditions.</EmailBlurb>
</Envelope>
```

Request has Account Id just in case if what to verify requests generated from this demo Account Id.

Comment: If you're looking for feedback here on StackOverflow, I'd suggest that you post the code you're using to create the envelopes.  If you think there's an issue with the service itself (i.e., your code used to result in emails being sent, and you haven't made any changes to your code but emails are suddenly no longer being sent), then I'd suggest you contact DocuSign Support (support@docusign.com).

Comment: Add the request payload, hope this helps in guide me further & the code I've used is the SDK SOAP sample code for this with DSAPI as endpoint. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the **CaptiveInfo** node from the request body (also removing the **ClientUserId** node that's located within it). DocuSign should send the signing invitation email to the recipient if you omit those elements from the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, That did the job.

Comment: is there a way to retrieve docusign console URL for email recipients too for example after CaptiveInfo node & in turn ClientUserId was commented so email notifications to recipients would trigger, in addition to that if I need to retrieve docusign console URL if client is available at my desk so that I can get it signed right away.. I don't see RequestRecipientToken would help as it requires ClientUserId as one of the parameter. Please advise.

Comment: Can you please add this as a new question?  (You'll be more likely to get an answer because most people won't notice the question here in the comments, and others will be more likely to benefit from the info in the future.)

Comment: Also -- can you please mark this answer as an "Accepted" answer (since it solved your original issue).  That way others will see that the question has an accepted answer and will be more likely to benefit from the info in the future.  Thanks!