# Docusign: Retrieve Console URL for Email recipients too

Tags: docusignapi

[Docusign Email delivery issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318536/docusign-email-delivery-issues/41338365#41338365)

After resolving above issue, I felt it would be better if I can retrieve Token URL even for email recipients. is there a way to retrieve docusign console URL for email recipients too for example after CaptiveInfo node & in turn ClientUserId was commented email notifications triggerred to recipients successfully, in addition to that if I need to retrieve docusign console URL if client is available at my desk so that I can get it signed right away.. I don't see RequestRecipientToken would help as it requires ClientUserId as one of the parameter. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **EmbeddedRecipientStartURL** property to value "**SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN**" for the signer (recipient) in the *Create Envelope* API request. It's my understanding that doing this will facilitate the scenario you describe -- i.e., creating an Envelope with a signer (recipient) that may either be a *remote* signer (i.e., will receive an email) or an *embedded* signer.  A detailed description of this property can be found [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm) (search the page for "embeddedRecipientStartURL").

Comment: The available merge fields items are: envelopeId, recipientId, recipientName, recipientEmail, and customFields. The customFields must be part of the recipient or envelope. The merge fields are enclosed in double brackets. 

Example: http://senderHost/[[mergeField1]]/ beginSigningSession? [[mergeField2]]&[[mergeField3]]


Could you please elaborate on senderHost & which mergefield corresponds to which property( envelopeId, recipientId, recipientName, recipientEmail etc)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on senderHost & what should be assigned to mergeField1, mergeField2, mergeField3 & mergeField4 properties?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the details re usage of those fields in this context. I'd suggest that you post a new question here on StackOverflow -- that way someone with DocuSign will be more likely to respond. (They likely aren't monitoring this comment thread.)