# Docusign Retrieve Signing Console URL: senderHost & mergeField details

Tags: docusignapi

[Sign at Docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387591/docusign-retrieve-console-url-for-email-recipients-too)

As per the above thread, it is possible to retrieve Signing console URL for email recipients too by setting **EmbeddedRecipientStartURL** property to value **"SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN"**, As per the documentation([Sign at Docusign](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm)), below example has to be framed in order to open Docusign Signing console.
    http://senderHost/[[mergeField1]]/beginSigningSession?[[mergeField2]]&[[mergeField3]]

Please explain what is senderHost & what should be filled in the mergeField properties accordingly? Let me know if you need any additional information related to this query.

Answer (score 2):

BVS, I believe that's the opposite. If you provide EmbeddedRecipientStartURL field with SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN, the signature will happen completely on DocuSign, and you don't have to provide any URL or merge fields.

> If the value SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN is used for this node, the recipient
>   will be directed to an embedded signing or viewing process directly at
>   DocuSign.

On the other hand, if you want to route the client through your own application BEFORE he or she goes to DocuSign, you could provide this kind of template URL with merge fields to better handle the request.

> Information can be appended to the embeddedRecipientStartURL using
>   merge fields. ***The available merge fields items are: envelopeId,
>   recipientId, recipientName, recipientEmail, and customFields.*** The
>   customFields must be part of the recipient or envelope. The merge
>   fields are enclosed in double brackets.

By example: if you wanted to handle the request before the signer goes to DocuSign, you could send something like https://senderHost?envId=[[envelopeId]]&email=[[recipientEmail]]. Sender host is your host, so it can be anything on the internet (www.yoursite.com, by example).

Hope it helps!